# Onos controller can’t detect hosts without specifying src and dst mac addresses

Tags: rest, sdn, topology, onos

Am configuring new application
that detects network through onos switches then make all hosts ping each other. ( i dont want to use fwd or ifwd apps)

By starting mininet with simple linear 2 topology, i made the application but i can’t see that the mac addresses are injected in switch flow table automatically although am enabling lldp and arp on them, i must manually add each and every mac address to the flow table

Can someone give a hint on how to make it generic?

Answer (score 0):

You might need the proxyarp activated first. Also, the fwd app will insert more than the MACs, I think by default it will use MACs, IPs and if possible ports as matching fields in the flow rule.